# Is there a way to downgrade a operating system on a azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, system-administration

I was looking to change virtual machine from one version of windows server to a complete different version. I was curious if there is a way to do this without making a new virtual machine on azure and migrating the data from the old machine to the new.

Comment: Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a Microsoft Azure virtual machine. (For more information, see KB  [401499](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4014997)7.)

Instead, you should create a new Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the operating system that is required and then migrate the workload.

Instructions for how to migrate Windows Server roles and features are available in the following [Install, use, and remove Windows Server migration tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134202)

Comment: Any update to the issue?